# Get unique list of strings by string substring

Tags: python

I made this working code but maybe it's possible to make it shorter?

```
sents_str = 'dimplegalla:28082000 dimplegalla:28082000'

sents = sents_str.split(' ')
uniqueList = []
uniqueRes = []

for letter in sents:
    if letter.split(':')[1] not in uniqueList:
        uniqueList.append(letter.split(':')[1])
        uniqueRes.append(letter)
print(uniqueRes)
```

Comment: note: you disregard any differences in the first part of the `.split(':')` (which happens to always be `'dimplegalla'` in your example). Is that intentional?

Comment: Given just the code you have posted, then: `print([sents_str.split()[0]])`. But I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: what is the expected output if `sents_str = 'dimplegalla0:28082000 dimplegalla1:28082000'`? And what about `'a:0:0 b:0:1'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
list({sub for sub in sents_str.split()})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```py
In [1]: sents_str = 'dimplegalla:28082000 dimplegalla:28082000'

In [2]: list(set(sents_str.split()))
Out[2]: ['dimplegalla:28082000']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sents_str = 'dimplegalla:28082000 dimplegalla:28082000'
uniqueList= [l.split(':')[1] for l in list(set(sents_str.split(' ')))]
uniqueRes = list(set(sents_str.split(' ')))
print(uniqueList)
print(uniqueRes)
```